# After creating an attribute i can get it only after i wait some time

Tags: magento-1.9

this is a thing that happend almost all the time i need to create a new custom attribute, for example for a category.

I correctly add the new attribute in the setup file of my module, 
it correctly appear in the backend and i can edit/change it with success.

BUT, when i try to get that attribute in the frontend it simply return an empty string.

This for just some time, after i wait without doing nothing it magically start returning the correct data and i can't understand how is possible.

This is a pain when i have to release things on production, can someone illuminate me ?

Sometimes deleting manually the content of var/cache/* do the job, sometimes not.

Below some piece the piece of code that i usually use to get the attribute:

```
$categoryIds = array(8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

$collection= Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in' => $categoryIds));
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('max_meals');

$limits = array();
foreach ($collection as $category)
    $limits[$category->getId()] = $category->getMaxMeals() > 0 ? $category->getMaxMeals() : 0;
```

Comment: It's due to database lock. You need to clear var/locks folder after you add an attribute add it will work without waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Besides flushing the cache, which you can do within `System > Cache Management` inside of the admin panel, I would also reindex. This is located in `System > Index Management`.

I have attached an image of the index that will most likely need the update:
[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Already cleared cache and reindexed a lot of times, nothing changes.